# Problem with the implementation of va_arg in my function

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

I am currently debugging my printf project for school, basically i just have to redo the function but i am encountering a problem that i can't understand.

Here is my code :

```
#include "ft_printf.h"

int ft_putchar(int c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
    return (1);
}

int ft_format(va_list args, const char format)
{
    if (format == 'c')
        return (ft_putchar(va_arg(args, int)));
    return (-1);
}

int ft_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    size_t  i;
    int     print_length;
    va_list args;

    i = 0;
    print_length = 0;
    va_start(args, format);
    while (format[i])
    {
        if (format[i] == '%')
        {
            i++;
            if (format[i] != '\0')
            {
                print_length += ft_format(args, format[i]);
            }
        }
        else
            print_length += ft_putchar(format[i]);
        i++;
    }
    va_end(args);
    return (print_length);
}

int main(void)
{
    ft_printf("l%cl%cl%cl%c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
    printf("l%cl%cl%cl%c\n", 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
}
```

The result :

ft_printf : lalalala | printf : lalblcld

I cant understand why it doesn't work properly when i try to print many arguments, so if someone can help me figure out where the problem is..

What i tried :

I tried to add va_arg(args, int); after calling ft_format and it worked properly ! but i still don't understand why this case isn't treated directly in my ft_format function ?

```
int ft_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    size_t  i;
    int     print_length;
    va_list args;

    i = 0;
    print_length = 0;
    va_start(args, format);
    while (format[i])
    {
        if (format[i] == '%')
        {
            i++;
            if (format[i] != '\0')
            {
                print_length += ft_format(args, format[i]);
                                a_arg(args, int);
            }
        }
        else
            print_length += ft_putchar(format[i]);
        i++;
    }
    va_end(args);
    return (print_length);
}
```

Output :

ft_printf : lalblcld | printf : lalblcld

Comment: That sprawling `if` chain could be a more concise `switch`.

Comment: Probably because you are passing `args` by value.

Comment: I thought it might be the copy as well. Consider a [mcve] that others could compile and test without having to invent the rest of the ft_* functions.

Comment: Hello @tadman , i know that but i have to respect the norm of my school when it comes to coding

Comment: Not seeing the issue here: https://godbolt.org/z/jc155Poqh Are you still seeing it with the code currently in the question? Seems like a bunch was removed in the edit that may have been relevant. Id does fail in Visual Studio with minor edits to allow it to compile. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Hey @RetiredNinja you're right, thank you for the advice (i edited the code and added my putchar function)

Comment: @RetiredNinja I code on iTerm with vim on Mac Os, and i compile with gcc

Comment: `ft_putchar` is non-portable.  It will only work on a little-endian architecture, where the address of an integer refers to the low-order byte.  To make it portable, assign the value to a `char`, then pass the address of the `char` to `write`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [C11 7.16 Variable arguments <stdarg.h>](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16):
<sup>*(Emphasis and formatting mine)*</sup>

> The type declared is
>
> ```
>     va_list
> ```
>
> which is a complete object type suitable for holding information needed by the macros `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end`, and `va_copy`. If access to the varying arguments is desired, the called function shall declare an object (generally referred to as *ap* in this subclause) having type `va_list`. **The object *ap* may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the `va_arg` macro with parameter ap, the value of *ap* in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the `va_end` macro prior to any further reference to *ap*.**

and

> It is permitted to create a pointer to a `va_list` and pass that pointer to another function, in which case the original function may make further use of the original list after the other function returns.

So after `ft_format` returns, `va_end` must be called on `args` to restore it from an indeterminate state.

But, [C11 7.16.1.3 The va_end macro](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16.1.3) also has this to say: <sup>*(Emphasis and formatting mine)*</sup>

> The `va_end` macro facilitates a normal return from the function whose variable argument list was referred to by the expansion of the `va_start` macro, or the function containing the expansion of the `va_copy macro`, that initialized the `va_list` *ap*. **The `va_end` macro may modify *ap* so that it is no longer usable (without being reinitialized by the `va_start` or `va_copy` macro).** If there is no corresponding invocation of the `va_start` or `va_copy` macro, or if the `va_end` macro is not invoked before the return, the behavior is undefined.

As far as I can tell, you have two options:

Use `va_copy` to create a copy of your `va_list` object in its current state

```
if (format[i] != '\0')
{
    va_list tmp;
    va_copy(tmp, args);
    print_length += ft_format(tmp, format[i]);
    va_end(tmp);
}
```

and pass that object to `ft_format`.

Or, define `ft_format` as

```
int ft_format(va_list *args, const char format)
```

and pass it a pointer to your `va_list` object

```
print_length += ft_format(&args, format[i]);
```

and

```
return (ft_putchar(va_arg(*args, int)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations ! i understand better now !